# Ember With Node and Express User Authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, ember.js

I need to develop user login and authentication to my ember.js application
my backend runs on Node and Express
I have extensively searched and found no good guide on how to implement that
it will be a great help if you can explain how exactly the process should be on both Client and server side.

p.s-I need to authenticate users from my mongo database. not 3rd party service provides

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 has a good starter guide [Create your first ember 2.0 app from authentication to calling an api](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/08/11/create-your-first-ember-2-dot-0-app-from-authentication-to-calling-an-api/)